# Alternative GWT Designer for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gwt, designer, uibinder, gwt-2.7

Is there anyone who knows an alternative for the GWT Designer in Eclipse or maybe a good workflow to design UI’s?
The GWT Designer is no longer supported, since GWT version 2.7.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's a Vaadin product but: have a look at the Vaadin Designer https://vaadin.com/designer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For Native GWT there is nothing.**

For GWT from other vendors

1. Vaadin -> https://vaadin.com/designer
2. GXT -> Nothing

Comment: Thx for your answers. I don't wanna change my project to Vaadin just because the designer. Do you have an Idea how other GWT developer Design her UI’s for the Ui-Binder without using a designer?
I know that I can write my UI creation in Java source code or write my XML manually but in my opinion, is it not very effective and comfortable.

Comment: That is the only option. The UX/UI team builds the html/css and the GWT Team wraps it around in UIBinder. Or the GWT Team builds Java GUI and UI team helps out with padding/margin.